# LLVM Test Infrastructure Fails

Tags: testing, integration-testing, llvm

I have successfully followed all of the steps for installing LLVM's test infrastrucure (LNT) located at [this link](http://llvm.org/docs/lnt/quickstart.html). The final step is to execute the following command:

```
lnt runtest nt \
    --sandbox SANDBOX \
    --cc ~/llvm.obj/Release/bin/clang \
    --test-suite ~/llvm-test-suite
```

I replaced the command with my values as follows:

```
lnt runtest nt \
    --sandbox ~/mysandbox \
    --cc /opt/llvm/Debug+Asserts/bin/clang++ \
    --test-suite ~/llvm-test-suite
```

When I run this command, I see the following output:

```
2013-05-16 14:43:27: checking source versions
2013-05-16 14:43:32: scanning for LNT-based test modules
2013-05-16 14:43:32: found 0 LNT-based test modules
2013-05-16 14:43:32: using nickname: 'routemapper__clang_DEV__x86_64'
2013-05-16 14:43:32: starting test in '/home/routemapper/mysandbox/test-2013-05-14_12-44-27'
2013-05-16 14:43:32: configuring...
2013-05-16 14:43:40: executing "nightly tests" with -j4...
2013-05-16 15:06:09: executing test modules
2013-05-16 15:06:09: loading nightly test data...
nt.py:810: fatal error: nightly test failed, no report generated
```

I think the following snippet from the `test log` might have something to do with it:

```
yacc -d /home/routemapper/llvm-test-suite/MultiSource/Applications/Burg/gram.y
make[4]: yacc: Command not found
make[4]: *** [y.tab.h] Error 127
yacc -d /home/routemapper/llvm-test-suite/MultiSource/Applications/Burg/gram.y
make[4]: yacc: Command not found
```

Any idea why I might be receiving this error with the example LNT cases even though I followed the Quick Start guide down to the letter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`make[4]: yacc: Command not found`

This should give you the hint. You need to install `yacc` tool which is required for the tests, apparently. How to install it will depend on the platform you are using.